# oledb in web.config c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm trying to use excel sheet as my database. I'm converting it into a datatable. When I try to pass the connectionstring in my method it populates with an exception:

> Input string was not in correct format.

And I found that error is in my Web.Config file. I used the following config:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
  <add name ="Excel07ConString" 
       connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xlsx)};DBQ=xlsx HDR={1}'"
       providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following connection string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name ="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=&quotD:\Desky\Excel_to_Datatable\Excel_to_Datatable\Files\DB in Excel.xlsx&quot; Extended Properties=&quotExcel 12.0;IMEX=1&quot;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

Comment: "Excel 12.0;IMEX=1\" here white space error i s coming @ Yuri

Answer (score 5):

You are using placeholders in the connection string, such as `Data Source={0}`. You have to fill in the appropriate values in those placeholders, for instance `Data Source='C:\Excel Sheets\MyFile.xslx'`.

Comment: Have you replaced both `{0}` and `{1}` by appropriate values and if so, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: '<add name ="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={D:\Desky\Excel_to_Datatable\Excel_to_Datatable\Files\DB in Excel.xlsx};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xlsx)};DBQ=xlsx HDR={Yes}'" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>' thus how i did @ Roy

Comment: Still it throws input string was not in correct format

Comment: No `{}` around the file paths or around Yes.

Comment: please suggest me some other solution buddy @ Roy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70842/discussion-between-selvasudar-dt-and-roy-dictus).

Answer (score 1):

You need to substitute some values in place of {0}(data source) and {1}(HDR).

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<data source here>;
Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;Driver={Microsoft Excel 
Driver(*.xlsx)};DBQ=xlsx HDR=<Yes/No>
```

> > "HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.
> >
> > "Data Source" Indicates source file path.

Comment: @SelvasudarDT You just need to update `<data source here>` with your excel file path and  replace <Yes/No> with Yes if you have first row as header.

Comment: still same status @ jeni..suggest me some links please